# Pass a class as argument to a NSThread

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, nsthread

How can I pass a class as argument to a thread using NSThread. In windows I was doing something like:

```
DWORD WINAPI threadFunc(LPVOID mpThis) {
    MYCLSS *pThis = reinterpret_cast<MYCLSS*>(mpThis);
  ....

void MYCLSS::func() {
  CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadFunc, (void*)this, 0, NULL);
  ....
```

For Mac I have not found any examples of this kind. Please help me

Comment: Recommendation: Don't try to program in one language they way you would in another. It almost always leads to pain. You may not be able to find what you are looking for because you're expecting C/C++ thinking rather than Objective C thinking.

Comment: You don't have to use `NSThread` to start a new thread on MacOS.  You should be able to use [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsthread/1415633-detachnewthreadselector

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it can be like windows

```
class CLS_CPP {
public:
  void Func();
  void Check();
  int var_check;
};

@interface CLS_OSX : NSObject {
@public
  void *obj;
}
-(void)osx_thread;
@end
@implementation CLS_OSX
-(void)osx_thread {  
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
    CLS_CPP *pThis = reinterpret_cast<CLS_CPP*>(obj);
  pThis->Check();
  NSLog(@"Check var %d", pThis->var_check);
  [NSThread exit];
  [pool drain];
}
@end

void CLS_CPP::Func() {
  var_check=77;
  CLS_OSX *trgt=[[CLS_OSX alloc] init]; 
  trgt->obj=(void*)this;
  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(osx_thread) toTarget:trgt withObject:trgt];
}
void CLS_CPP::Check() {
  NSLog(@"CLS_CPP::Check success");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
     
  CLS_CPP oAPP;
  oAPP.Func();  
    
}
```

Comment: I get an error that I don't know what it's from: objc[862]: Object 0x100114020 of class NSThread autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug. Any ideea?

Comment: You need an autorelease pool.   Either because you're running in a thread in a run loop or dispatch queue or because you manually created an NSAutoreleasePool.

All of this is a very non-standard pattern.   What are you doing in the 'osx_thread'?  If it is any sort of interaction with the system, it is unlikely to work as expected.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying... It's already working the way I want, except for this error.

Comment: It's not all code, in the main was  while (true) { sleep(60); }

Comment: Solve it, need AutoreleasePool on the main() or on the CLS_CPP::Func()

Comment: That probably hasn't really fixed it.  `while (true) { sleep(60); } ` is not at all the way a program on macOS or iOS should ever be written.  It is completely wrong and will cause problems.